# Generic Type parameter and the dynamic type

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, dynamic

I want to know, in the example below, is the `if` statement in `TrickyGenericMethod` is a bad idea or if in certain situations it would be ok.  In my case, I have a factory method, that uses the generic parameter to produce the correct result.  Unfortunately, if the type reference of the object that is passed in is a reference to an interface or an abstract class, it will produce an incorrect result because `T` is not the actual type of the object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HasGenericMethod hgm = new HasGenericMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(hgm.GenericMehtod("string"));
        Console.WriteLine(hgm.GenericMehtod((object)"object"));

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(hgm.TrickyGenericMethod("string"));
        Console.WriteLine(hgm.TrickyGenericMethod((object)"object"));


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class HasGenericMethod
{
    public string GenericMehtod<T>(T param)
    {
        return  "Type of T:\t" + typeof(T) + "\tType of param:\t" + param.GetType();
    }

    public string TrickyGenericMethod<T>(T param)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != param.GetType())
        {
            return TrickyGenericMethod((dynamic)param);
        }
        return "Type of T:\t" + typeof(T) + "\tType of param:\t" + param.GetType(); ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> is the if statement in TrickyGenericMethod is a bad idea

Yes, it looks like it to me. In particular, if you call this from a different assembly using a  value of an internal type (and it goes through this path once), the "execution time compiler" will use the best accessible type for the `dynamic` call... so you'll end up with a stack overflow.

EDIT: Sample code for that...

```
// Library.cs
using System;

public class Library
{
    public static void Foo<T>(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", typeof(T), value.GetType());
        if (typeof(T) != value.GetType())
        {
            dynamic d = value;
            Foo(d);
        }
    }
}

// Test.cs
class Internal {}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {
        Library.Foo<object>(new Internal());
    }
}
```

Result:

```
System.Object : Internal
System.Object : Internal
...
System.Object : Internal

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

There may be other similar situations where it doesn't quite work, too. I would try to avoid relying on `typeof(T) == value.GetType()` as far as possible.

You could *unconditionally* call a private implementation method using dynamic typing, so that you end up only trying this once, and ending up with "best effort" approach.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  I've been looking with not much luck to see how the DRT decides which type to use in this case.  Do you know where this would be documented?

Comment: @SeattleLeonard: The C# spec leaves this mostly implementation-defined, I'm afraid. I'll look for a bit more documentation later on.

Comment: @jbtule: Does it not? Even from a different assembly? Hmm... must try it tomorrow.

Comment: @jbtule: I've just managed to provoke a stack overflow... will post my code.

Comment: @jbtule whoops, my mistake i used Library.Foo(new Internal()); to start things off.

Answer (score 0):

1st, it's a bad idea because you are using recursion in an unnecessary way, you have at most one other call so why make it recursive, a private helper method would be more clear and less error prone as a general practice.

2nd, you are testing for when T is going to be equal to `GetType()` and recursing until it is, thus just use the result of `GetType()` directly and be done with it.

Comment: You're right that I should just use GetType and be done with it. That is actually what I decided to go with, but you are wrong about a couple things.  The parameter being passed in is not dynamic in this case.  If the reference to the parameter in the calling function was to an interface then it will not be == to GetType().  Second, I will defer to Jon that even when a dynamic is passed in, that it still may not be equal.